# ssis - beautify json string

Tags: c#, json, ssis

I'm trying to beautify a json string, I'm getting it by:

```
 string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Row, Formatting.Indented);
```

and seems it's working pretty well, but it includes _IsNull fields, how I can avoid that?

```
"ID": 35208,
"ID_IsNull": false,
"name": "SONIA",
"name_IsNull": false
```

I would have:

```
"ID": 35208,
"name": "SONIA"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the best way is to implement a contract resolver and auto-ignore all properties that have the _IsNull name suffix:

```
    private class IgnoredNullIndicationPropertiesJsonContractResolver : DefaultContractResolver
    {
        protected override JsonProperty CreateProperty(MemberInfo member, MemberSerialization memberSerialization)
        {
            var property = base.CreateProperty(member, memberSerialization);

            if (property.PropertyName.EndsWith("_IsNull"))
            {
                property.Ignored = true;
            }

            return property;
        }
    }
```

You can then apply it using a JSON serializer like this:

```
var serializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings
                    {
                        ContractResolver = new IgnoredNullIndicationPropertiesJsonContractResolver(),
                    };

                    string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Row, Formatting.Indented, serializerSettings);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it's perfect!